# state is disconnected and Connectivity is unknown in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet, nmcli

The State of device eth0 is unmanaged, I had make a connection to this interface and locking a profile to eth0, but not had been happened.
How can I change it's status to managed?
please Help me.

```
$ nmcli -p dev status

=====================
  Status of devices
=====================
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
--------------------------------------------------------------
eth0    ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --

$ nmcli -p g status

=========================
  NetworkManager status
=========================
STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
disconnected  unknown       enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHGJF.jpg)

Comment: @Hessam what is the output of `nmcli connection show` ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.